# Create app folder after installing KivyMD apk file and read txt file from the folder

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivymd

Please I have created a kivymd app and it's running well on my android device. The app reads the names from a txt file, randomise them and group them into preferred number of groups. It works fine but I want to add functionality that users can add their own txt file into a folder created by the app after installation so that the app will read the txt file from the root folder.

Now I need a way that the app can create the folder by itself after installation. And also how the app can read txt files from that folder for the grouping.

Thanks in advance

```
import random
import kivymd
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.graphics.context import Clock
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex
from kivymd.app import MDApp

from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineListItem

Window.fullscreen = True
Window.maximize()


class CardOn(MDCard):
    pass


class ListItems(OneLineListItem):
    text = StringProperty()


class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    pass


class NavigationDrawerIconButton(BoxLayout):
    pass


class NavigationLayout(Screen):
    state = ''
    my_text = "No names loaded yet"
    convert_to_string = "No names loaded yet"
    raw_file = open("Name.txt", "r")
    read_content = raw_file.read()
    class_split = read_content.split("\n")
    num_of_generated_groups = StringProperty()
    Shuffled_list = []
    grouping_critera = StringProperty()
    student_total = 0
    Groups = NumericProperty(1)
    hint = StringProperty()
    Randomized_list = []
    Created_groups = []
    refined_group = StringProperty(""" """)
    students_to_string = StringProperty("No names loaded yet")
    my_index = NumericProperty
    new_titles = StringProperty()

    def group_criteria(self, value):
        self.grouping_critera = value
        if self.grouping_critera == "Number of groups":
            self.hint = "Select desired number of groups"
        elif self.grouping_critera == "Number of groups":
            self.grouping_critera = "Number of groups"
        else:
            self.hint = "Select desired students per groups"
        print(self.grouping_critera)

    def group_nums(self, value):
        self.Groups = int(value)
        print(self.Groups)

    def read_names(self):
        raw_file = open("Name.txt", "r")
        read_content = raw_file.read()
        self.class_split = read_content.split("\n")

    def create_groups(self):
        self.student_total = len(self.class_split)

        self.Shuffled_list = self.class_split
        random.shuffle(self.Shuffled_list)

        self.Groups = int(self.Groups)

        if self.grouping_critera == "Number of groups":
            groups_to_students = round(self.student_total / self.Groups)
            self.Created_groups = [self.Shuffled_list[i * groups_to_students:(i + 1) * groups_to_students] for i in
                                   range((len(self.Shuffled_list) + groups_to_students - 1) // groups_to_students)]
        else:
            self.Created_groups = [self.Shuffled_list[i * self.Groups:(i + 1) * self.Groups] for i in
                                   range((len(self.Shuffled_list) + self.Groups - 1) // self.Groups)]

        print(f"Created groups are {self.Created_groups}")

        for self.i in self.Created_groups:
            card = MDCard(orientation="vertical", padding="8dp", size_hint=(None, None),
                          size=(self.width, "10dp"),
                          pos_hint={"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5})
            self.ids.md_list.add_widget(card)

            self.num_of_generated_groups = f"{len(self.Created_groups)} Groups Generated"

            self.my_index = self.Created_groups.index(self.i) + 1  # the 1 will replace the index at 0
            label = MDLabel(text=f"Group {self.my_index} members =  {len(self.i)} ", theme_text_color="Custom",
                            text_color=(1, 1, 1, 1), halign="center", font_size=30)
            self.ids.md_list.add_widget(label)

            for e in self.i:
                self.ids.md_list.add_widget(ListItems(text=e))

    def clear_screen(self):
        self.ids.md_list.clear_widgets()

    def generate_groups(self):
        self.clear_screen()
        self.create_groups()


class GroupingApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)

    def build(self):
        return self.screen


if __name__ == '__main__':
    GroupingApp().run()
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Could you post what you have tried so far to resolve that issue and that does not work?

Comment: You can create a folder programmatically inside the `onCreate()` method of your main activity.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Please i have just added the snippet of my code

Comment: Thanks @AbhishekChoudhary for your response. Please could you elaborate more on the function for me because it is new to me.